# Validating input within a method with a while loop

Tags: c#, validation

I'm trying to implement a method that takes in 8 characters and the first 3 characters must be alphabets (First character must start with "S"), I've tried implementing a while loop but it does not seem to be working, could you please let me know what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

```
static string VerifiedInputVRNString()
{
    string VRNInput = Console.ReadLine();
    string VRNUpper = VRNInput.ToUpper();

    while (VRNUpper.Length != 8 && 
           VRNUpper[0] != 'S' && 
           Char.IsLetter(VRNUpper[1]) && 
           Char.IsLetter(VRNUpper[2]))
    {
        Console.Write("Please try again:");
        VRNUpper = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    return VRNUpper;
}
```

Comment: What does "but it does not seem to be working" mean? What does it do? (BTW - I'd take a look at your logic. You've got a lot of AND (&&) -- did you mean OR (||))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *regular expresion* in order to check if user input *matches* required pattern:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

static string VerifiedInputVRNString() {
  string result;

  while (!Regex.IsMatch(result = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(), @"^S\p{L}{2}.{5}$"))
    Console.Write("Please try again:");

  return result;
}
```

Here we use `^S\p{L}{2}.{5}$` *pattern* which is

```
^        - anchor, beginning of the string
S        - letter 'S'
\p{L}{2} - exactly 2 letters (of any language)
.{5}     - exactly 5 arbitrary characters
$        - anchor, end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 while  (VRNUpper.Length < 8 || VRNUpper[0] != 'S' || ! ( Char.IsLetter(VRNUpper[1]) && Char.IsLetter(VRNUpper[2]) )
{
....
}
```